# How to pass the result of the previous GitLab jobs to following jobs?

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, yaml-anchors

I am new to gitlab ci. I have gitlab ci yml in which one command is used in 2 different jobs as below.

```
jobA:
  script:
    - yarn test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: ./cobertura-coverage.xml
      junit:
        - ./junit.xml

jobB:
  script:
    - 'yarn test || :'
```

I need to pass the result/artifacts of the previous GitLab jobs to following jobs (For example, in this case from JobA to JobB).  My question is, how can achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "pass the result" to another job. Do you mean you want to deduplicate your YAML but still have two jobs that run `yarn test` or only one job that runs `yarn test`?

Comment: @sytech you can see in the script in the question. 2 jobs (A and B) running the yarn test as mentioned in the question. And the result of the script from jobA needs to passed to jobB for the script (yarn test).

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear to me what you would want this pipeline to do when it is run. What exactly do you mean by "the result"? Do you mean the exit code? The text output? Or what? How is the result of `yarn test` in Job A supposed to be used by `yarn test` in job B? Can you give an example of a scenario and the desired output?

Comment: @sytech yes exactly. How is the result of yarn test in Job A supposed to be used by yarn test in job B?

Comment: @sytech I have edited the question it may help you. Thanks